# Not Having to Specify Command-Line Options Each Time

Tags: python, scons

I am using scons to build on windows. My SConscript file takes certain command line options to build like OS=win7 CPU=x86_64 etc. Every time I run scons from command line I have to type these options, Is there a way I can put them in SConscript file or set an environment variable so that I don't have to type them every time I build.

I tried setting SCONSFLAGS but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make a script to execute the exact command you need, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call([
        'scons',
        'OS=win7',
        'CPU=x86_64'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling on Windows, SCons should detect that, so you shouldnt need to set `OS=win7`.

As for the CPU, you can set that when creating the Environment, as follows:

```
env = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = 'x86_64')
```

You can find more information about the TARGET_ARCH Construction Variable [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a5025.html).

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work bu just setting an environment variable on Windows, TEST ="OS=win7 CPU=x86_64" and then running the scons script as scons %TEST%